# HTML Foot on page 2

Tags: html, css, footer

I am making a PHP report and depending on the data received from the database is how long each page will be, I would like some text at the bottom of the last page when it is printed (doesn't matter what it really looks like on screen).

I have this for the footer, but it is showing it at the bottom of the first page, not the last page, Any help to move this would greatly be appreciated.

CSS:

```
@media print{
.footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="footer">Text 1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

that means you have a pagination right ?

if yes you have to check it in php. if the last page comes pass some parameter to the view. then check if the parameter is true sho the footer

for example in PHP do this :

```
if ($pagination.last) $last = true;
```

in HTML :

```
<?php if ($last) { ?><span class="footer">Text 1</span><?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, this has not made any difference, It does't matter where the`<span class="footer">Text 1</span>` is in the source, with the current CSS it will always print at the bottom of the first page, moving the footer class only changes where it is on the screen within the web browser.  I have also tried your solution with out any CSS, it just places the text at the end of the last page, not the bottom, so if the last page is only half full, then this footer will be in the middle of the printed page.